How do we express that the foundation of a body of knowledge that has not been learned properly?
They teach English from 1st grade to 12th grade in Vietnam.
In the first grade, they teach very basic things such as different kinds of colors or days of the week. For higher grades, they teach tenses and more complicated English structures.
A lazy student goes through all these grades but he doesn't learn English properly.
Now, he's graduated high school but knows almost nothing about English.
If you ask him to read all days of a week. He may know Monday or Sunday but can't remember the other days.
How do we express that the foundation of a body of knowledge that has not been learned properly?
In Vietnamese, we say "he lost the foundation of English subject".
Some suggest saying "He is weak in English basics".

I think you’re asking How do we express that the foundation of a body of knowledge  [ ] has not been learned properly?

You could express it in various ways, for example "He didn't concentrate in English lessons, so very little 'went in'". "He never learned the basics of English properly."

In Vietnamese, the verb is "lose"?  Doesn't that imply that at one time he had a foundation, when what you've described is a poor foundation, really no firm foundation at all?

If he knows some parts (maybe even some advanced parts) but has not learned some of the basics, you might say something like:
He has (some) fundamental gaps in his knowledge of English.
‘Fundamental’ here indicates that the gaps include foundational, essential material.
For other subjects, you might instead use ‘…his understanding’ for principles, rules, and concepts, and reserve ‘knowledge’ for words/meanings, facts, and other items to be committed to memory.  However, in the case of a language, ‘understanding’ would refer to the ability to comprehend others' writing or speech in that language, as distinct from being able to speak or write it yourself.

He has mostly forgotten what little English he learned in school.
P.S. It is a mistake to believe that English always reduces something to an adage or a pat phrase, or that there is always one "standard" way of expressing an idea or situation.

A student who has never learnt a language properly, even after studying it 7 to 12 years, you could say:

He may have studied English at school but he can't speak it
He can barely say a word in English.
He doesn't know English even though he studied it for 12 years.

(Bear in mind, these are hyperbolic statements used for emphasis)
If someone graduated high school, despite narrowly passing English tests, I might describe their level of English as being very basic, or

He knows enough to scrape by.
He lacks basic English.



He lost the foundation of English subject.

doesn't sound right to convey the meaning.

He is weak in English basics.

doesn't say that the weakness is due to the failure to learn during those years. It could be due to long stays overseas afterwards that led to the deterioration.
We could consider
He didn't build up his foundation of the English language (due to various reasons
during the foundation years).

A very basic knowledge of a second language may be described as a rudimentary or survival-level knowledge of it (the latter suggesting that it is enough to 'survive' or 'get by' in the country that speaks it). In English, we sometimes describe a very basic or rudimentary knowledge of another language as being "tourist" or "holiday" (vacation) level - for example, if you can ask the way to the beach and order a coffee in French we might say you can speak "tourist French". We would also describe such a level as "not conversational" to mean they can say a few phrases but not have a conversation with a native speaker, for example "I can speak a little French but I'm not conversational".

"Rudimentary" is more what I would say about someone who has only studied a small portion of the language, but they might nonetheless have learned that small portion well. The OP's situation seems different than that.

@LeeMosher The situation is not 100% clear but that's why I've given multiple options.


In Vietnamese, we say "he lost the foundation of English subject".

I feel like retaining the word "lost" might be the best way to stay close to the original meaning. There is a standard phrase in English which will work.
You could say:

The basics of English are lost on him.
Basic English is lost on him.
The foundations of English are lost on him.
The fundamentals of English are lost on him.

This suggests the opportunity to learn has been wasted on the student.
However, people don't say any of these:

She loses the basics of English on him.
English is losing on him.
He is losing the basics of English.
He lost the basics of English.

See https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/be-lost-on
Or: https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/lost%20on
